# convert JSON object to Prometheus metrics format using jq

Tags: json, newline, jq

Consider a JSON object like

```
{
  "foo": 42,
  "baz": -12,
  "bar{label1=\"value1\"}": 12.34
}
```

constructed by [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) using some data source. The actual key names and their amount may vary, but the result will always be an object with numbers (int or float) as values. The keys may contain quotation marks, but no whitespaces.

Can I use jq to format the object into a [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)-compatible format so I can just use the output to push the data to a Prometheus Pushgateway?

The required result would look like

```
foo 42
bar{label1="value1"} 12.34
baz -12
```

i.e. space-separated with newlines (no `\r`) and without quotes except for the label value.

I can't use bash for post-processing and would therefore prefer a pure jq solution if possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `keys_unsorted` to get object keys (`keys` does the same as well but the former is faster), generate desired output by means of string interpolation.

```
$ jq -r 'keys_unsorted[] as $k | "\($k) \(.[$k])"' file
foo 42
baz -12
bar{label1="value1"} 12.34
```

And, by adding `-j` option and printing line feed manually as @peak suggested you can make this portable.

Comment: note: The order of appearance in the output doesn't matter for prometheus metrics.

Comment: @hek2mgl Okay, but I used `keys_unsorted` because it's faster than both `keys` and `to_entries`.

Comment: true, that's why just a note

Answer (score 4):

On a Windows platform, jq will normally use CR-LF for newlines; to prevent this, use the -j command-line option and manually insert the desired 'newline' characters like so:

```
jq -rj 'to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)\n"' file
```